# Is it possible to make the Button execute two or more actions?

Tags: syntax, button

According to the help:

> Button[label,action]

Is it possible to make the button execute two actions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at  [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html?q=CompoundExpression&lang=en) :

```
Button["Click Here", Print[10!]; Print[11!]]
```

> ```
>  "Click Here"
> ```

when clicked it performs two actions

> ```
> 3628800
> 39916800
> ```

Comment: Thanks for it, I didn't know about the existance of compoundEpression.

Answer (score 6):

Use `CompoundExpression`, which will be more familiar in the form of the `;` operator (which many wouldn't recognize as an operator at all).

This works anywhere where a single command seems to be called for in a syntax description. `CompoundExpression` returns the result of the last operation or `Null` if there isn't any.

Answer (score 2):

`Module[]` while a bit longer seems to work too:

```
Button["Click Here", Module[{}, {Print[10!], Print[11!]}]]
```

Comment: Module is unecessary here: you simply use `List` to substitute `CompoundExpression`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar - List works great, I just thought that Module might provide more flexibility to do more things than Print.  The OP asked "Is it possible to make the button execute two actions?" "...two actions?" covers lots of possible ground.

Comment: @Jagra Please try `Button["Click Here", {Print[10!], Print[11!]}]` and `Button["Click Here", Print[10!]; Print[11!]]`. `Module` does nothing in this case.